# How do determine the type of data in S3.getObject()

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

The node.js API for S3 gives the following description for the data returned in the callback of `getObject`. From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property :

> Body — (Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream) Object data.

Is this for real? Is there no way to control which of these things it is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know if you can control in advance the type of the data.Body field provided in the getObject() callback. If all you want to do is determine if you've received a buffer, you can try [Node's Buffer.isBuffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_isbuffer_obj)(data.Body) class method.

Alternately, you might want to avoid the issue altogether and use this approach from Amazon's [S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html#Amazon_S3__Streaming_Objects_to_Files_on_Disk__getObject_):

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myImageFile.jpg'};
var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('/path/to/file.jpg');
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
```

Presuming you'll be using this code in a typical node.js async callback environment, it might make more sense to see the code like so:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function downloadFile(key, localPath, callback) {
  var s3 = new AWS.S3();
  var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: key};
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(localPath);

  file.on('close') {
    callback();
  }

  file.on('error', function(err) {
    callback(err);
  });

  s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);
}
```

Comment: If the above code fails to download, how do you trap the error?

Comment: @Mike: Before or after the 'close' handler, add something like: file.on('error', function(err) { callback(err); });

Comment: I edited that error handler into the example. Should have been there in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any way to change the Body type either, however after noticing the Body was a buffer, I transformed the buffer into a ReadableStream with this handy & pretty straightforward [function](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/fb0f95f43ea958846d932bb4e79934a4a548155f/lib/util.js#L120): `AWS.util.buffer.toStream` (or perhaps you might want to use another lib like [streamifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamifier)).

I was looking for something where I could validate errors before doing anything else, in Amazon's example it translates to "create the Write Stream only if there were no errors".

```
s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    var file = require('fs').createWriteStream(name);
    var read = AWS.util.buffer.toStream(data.Body);

    read.pipe(file);
    read.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
    });
});
```